# Optimization of the sum of a convex and a non-convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, non-convex-optimization

I have two quadratic functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ which are convex (PSD Hessian)and non-convex respectively and $x\in R^{n}$.

Adding them together as $(1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda g(x)$ for $\lambda=\lambda^*$ their sum will become convex (PSD Hessian). So i can optimized it using quadratic programing.
$$x^*=\underset{x}{argmin} (1-\lambda^*)f(x)+\lambda^* g(x)$$
$$s.t. ~~x_i \ge 0$$

Function $g(x)$ has a saddle point minimum in $x=0$ and is also minimum at the boundaries.

Solving the above using QP, results in $x^*$.

Now if i solve the following for comparison: 
$$\tilde{x}=\underset{x}{argmin} f(x)$$
$$s.t. ~~x_i \ge 0$$
I observe:
$f(x^*)>f(\tilde{x})$ and $g(x^*)<g(\tilde{x})$ which shows having $g(x)$ was effective according to the purpose. But how can i justify that knowing $g(x)$ is still a non-convex added part in the fist optimization?!

The non-convexity of $g(x)$ doesn't effect the optimum solution as long as the whole object is convex? or it does?

In fact i know that if both $f$ and $g$ were convex, $\lambda$ could be a trade off between having the result closer to the optimum of one or the other, but when $g$ is not convex, i'm afraid i cannot say something like that for optimum point of $g$!

**EDIT:**

$f(x)=x^\top Q x+c^\top x$ and $g(x)=x^\top H x$, where $Q$ is symmetric-PD and $H$ is just symmetric, but $(Q+\lambda^*H)$ is PSD.

Comment: It does not. Indeed, when the whole objective function is convex, any stationary point of the optimization problem you gave is a global minimum, regardless of the components which make up the objective.

Comment: @Alex: i know that, but i meant how can i justify what happened: $g(x^*)<g(\tilde{x})$ ?

Comment: What's to justify? Just because $f(x) + g(x) < f(y) + g(y)$ does not mean that it _must_ be true that $f(x) < f(y)$ and $g(x) < g(y)$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Hi Micheal, I think i didn't exactly say that, did i ?!  I had a data driven observation as i stated above and i do not want to generalize it, but i want to better understand it. So i'm looking for some information regarding properties of such combinations and special cases, etc.

Comment: I know you didn't say that. My point is that there's no real principle here. The sum of a convex function and a non-convex function is sometimes convex. When it is, then you get to treat the sum as a whole in a convex optimization context---but you don't get to say anything about the individual components that went into it.

Comment: That said---since $g$ is quadratic you could break _it_ apart into its positive semidefinite and negative definite components, and treat them separately. Obviously it's only the negative definite component that has to be "cancelled out" somehow.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: i tried to cancel it out by adding a term k $x^\top x$ to it which resulted into having the above! But i do not want to alter $g(x)$ so much as its minimum is helpful to the general problem.